# Pandas Time series manipulation with large panel data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Here is my large panel dataset:

| Date | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-07-20 | 50 | 60 | Kevin |
| 2017-07-21 | 51 | 80 | Kevin |
| 2016-05-23 | 100 | 200 | Cathy |
| 2016-04-20 | 20 | 20 | Cathy |
| 2019-01-02 | 50 | 60 | Leo |

This dataset contains **billions of rows**. What I would like to do is that I would like to calculate the 1-day different in terms of percentage for x1 and x2: Denote t and t+1 to the time representing today and tomorrow. I would like to calculate `(x1_{t+1} - x2_t) / x2_t`

**First** I used the fastest way in terms of writing:

I created a nested list containing all the target values of each group of `x3`:

```
nested_list = []
flatten_list = []

for group in df.x3.unique():
    df_ = df[df.x3 == group]
    nested_list.append((df_.x1.shift(-1) / df_.x2) / df_.x2))
for lst in nested_list:
    for i in lst:
        flatten_list.append(i)

df["target"] = flatten_list
```

However, this method will literality take a year to run, which is not implementable.

I also tried the native pandas `groupby` method for potentially runnable outcome but it **DID NOT** seem to work:

```
def target_calculation(x):
    target = (x.x1.shift(-1) - x.x2) / x.x2
    return target

df["target"] = df.groupby("x3")[["x1", "x2"]].apply(target_calculation)
```

How can I calculate this without using for loop or possibly vectorize the whole process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `groupby` + `shift` "x1" and subtract "x2" from it:

```
df['target'] = (df.groupby('x3')['x1'].shift(-1) - df['x2']) / df['x2']
```

Output:

```
         Date   x1   x2     x3  target
0  2017-07-20   50   60  Kevin   -0.15
1  2017-07-21   51   80  Kevin     NaN
2  2016-05-23  100  200  Cathy   -0.90
3  2016-04-20   20   20  Cathy     NaN
4  2019-01-02   50   60    Leo     NaN
```

Note that

```
(df.groupby('x3')['x1'].shift(-1) / df['x2']) / df['x2']
```

produces the output equivalent to `flatten_list` but I don't think this is your true desired output but rather a typo.